# Flash ADC with TL074 & 74LS148: encoder inputs always high?

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, ttl

I am attempting to build a 3-bit 0-5V flash ADC using two TL074 quad op amps and a 74LS148 active-low priority encoder.

The circuit is fairly simple. 8 100K resistors are connected in series between 0V and +5V, with each node between connected to the inverting input of one of 7 op amps, providing 7 reference voltages for the comparators, equally spread between the supply rails. The input is connected to the non-inverting inputs of all 7 op amps. The op amps are also supplied from the 0V and +5V. Each op amp's output sits at about +1.4V until the input goes above its respective reference voltage, at which point it snaps up to about +3.6V.

My thought was that these could then directly drive the 74LS148 inputs (1 - 7, in reverse order, with input 0 grounded). If I interpret the voltages by hand according to the 74LS148's function table, I should get the (active-high) output I want. However, it seems that the inputs from the op amps are *always* being seen as high, even when they are at the low +1.4V state. (I do see occasional glitches where the outputs jump to a state other than all high.)

Is that +1.4V simply above or too near the logic threshold for the 74LS family? Research suggests not, but maybe I read something wrong? Or, are the output pins of the TL07x perhaps unable to sink enough current to drive the 74LS inputs low? Or is it something else?

Note that I also have -12V and +12V supplies available in this circuit, in case the op amp supply rails need to be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 74LS logic, 1.4 volts is an "undefined" value.  An input must be below 0.8 volts to guarantee it will be accepted as a Low, and above 2.0 volts to be a guaranteed High.

The inputs will source 0.8 mA when taken low, so your op-amps must be able to sink that current while keeping their output voltage below 0.8 volts.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Datasheet parse error.

Answer (score 2):

You ideally need a fast rail to rail type op-amp to bring the outputs closer to the 0-5v range.  Or you can use an open collector type op-amp (that guarantees pull down to 0v) with a pull up resistor on the output.

Comment: You don't want an op amp at all. They are not optimized for fast overload recovery, and there are other problems as well. See, for instance, http://www.ronamundson.com/tag/phase-inversion/ for a discussion and advice.

Comment: Use a comparator instead of an op amp. These can provide open-drain output, high speed, and hysteresis.

Comment: What is an open collector op amp?

Comment: An open collector op-amp (often just called a comparator) has the basic center circuitry of a op-amp but does not have the internal components that perform the equal output swing, it will only pull down, through an open collector.  A similar mosfet version would be called an open drain type.

Comment: Accepted the above because it answers the question directly, but I appreciate you putting me on to this (comparators) as it appears to be the solution I want.